# How do I programmatically rename a file(pictre) once I have saved it to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, upload, filesystems, rename

The app basically takes a picture, saves the image to a file and stores the file location in coredata.  From here I either choose to save/submit this image or discard it.  If the file is saved I want to leave it alone, if it's submitted I want to take the response and name the image that file, and if it's discarded I don't want it.

Ideally I want to just rename it after the response, but is this built in or will I have to do a few other steps?

Also, I've considered just submitting the raw data as well and renaming it after the reply but not sure if that would play well since I am submitting a dictionary.

Comment: it is not clear what "response" means. or what you mean by "submitting a dictionary". Have you considered adding a "name" attribute to your Photo entity and updating the name attribute from the response?

Comment: The app does a formsubmit of a dictionary to a webservice(one of items is the file location on the phone so it knows where to upload it from).  The webservice takes the photo and assigns it a unique ID and sends this response back to the app.  

I'm wondering if there is just a simple command to rename the file on the device(from whatever.jpg to newname.jpg) or if I will have to either 

a) copy with a new name and delete old or 
b) submit the raw data and deal with issues on the webservice side

Comment: "(one of items is the file location on the phone so it knows where to upload it from)" --> you have to put the image data in your POST. The filename can only be used by the CLIENT (your App) to locate the data to submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming a file is counterintuitive.

You use `-[NSFileManger moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:]`  or `-[NSFileManger moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:]` and supply a path with a different file name (last path component.) The file manager "moves" the file to the new path name thus renaming the file.